# GCP image storage strategy

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am working on a project where a photographer is going to upload a set of high-resolutions pictures (20 to 40 pictures). I am going to store each picture twice: 1 original and 1 with the watermark. On the platform, only pictures with a watermark are going to be displayed. The user will be able to buy pictures and the one selected are going to be send by email (original pictures).

bucket-name: `photoshoot-fr`

main-folder(s): `YYYY-MM-DD-HH_MODEL-NAME` example: `2020-01-03_Melania-Doul`

I am not sure here if I should have 2 different folder inside the previous folder which are `original` and `protected`. Both folders are going to contain the exact same pictures with the same `id` but one is going to store the original pictures and the other one protected pictures. Is there any better bucket design solution?

n.b: it's a personal project but there are multiple photographers and each photographers are going to upload 2-3 set of photos every day. Each `main-folder` is going to be deleted after 2 months.

Comment: The real question on this is how will you protect the picture and the access from the different phtographers? Can you detail this part?

Comment: Another thing to consider is whether the app exposes the path to the picture files directly.  If it does, then it would be simple to guess the name of the non-watermarked files and open them directly in a browser. If the different buckets/folder have different privileges for different parts of the app (part 1: web page preview, part 2: email pictures) then this potential problem could be avoided.